# set div 50% height with overflow auto

Tags: html

The first  should have vertical scroll bar when it's longer than 50% but it didn't work. I want to fix the 50% and if the text is longer it should show the scroll bar from the  overflow.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<style>
 html, body { height: 100%; }
</style>
<body>
 
 <table style="height:100%; width:100%" border=1>
  <tr style="height:50%">
   <td style="width:30%;">
    <div style="width:100px; height:50% overflow:auto;">
     <table>
      <tr><td>
      test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>
      test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>
      </td></tr>
     </table>
    </div>
   </td>
   <td width="70%"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="height:50%"><td></td><td></td></tr>
 </table>
  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm not sure if it is possible to do it in table, try with some div or other

Comment: its possible @Nicolas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing almost right ... just ,missing a huge comma :P  `<div style="width:100px; height:50% ;overflow:auto;">`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<style>
 html, body { height: 100%; }
</style>
<body>
 
 <table style="height:100%; width:100%" border=1>
  <tr style="height:50%">
   <td style="width:30%;">
    <div style="width:100px; height:50% ;overflow:auto;">
     <table>
      <tr><td>
      test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>
      test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>
      </td></tr>
     </table>
    </div>
   </td>
   <td width="70%"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="height:50%"><td></td><td></td></tr>
 </table>
  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How can i miss that huge coma. :D
Thanks a lot for pointing it out.

Comment: You can accept my answer if this helps you , don't miss that... :D